# Flex: Using NumericStepper as an itemEditor in a DataGrid

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, itemeditor

I am trying to make one field in a datagrid editable with a numeric stepper.  My current attempts look like they are working, but the dataProvider is not actually being changed.

Based on what I have read in a billion different places, the syntax should be

```
< mx:DataGridColumn dataField="a" itemRenderer="mx.controls.NumericStepper" rendererIsEditor="true" editorDataField="value" / >
```

I have tried several variations on this theme, and nothing seems to work.  What am I missing?

Comment: Can you post more of your code, including the DataProvider declaration? is your DataProvider [Bindable]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue it seems, was that I was expecting changes to be instantly reflected in the dataProvider, but they are not applied until the editor loses focus.

Answer (score 0):

Without any more info, I would guess that your dataProvider is not declared as Bindable.